# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file error for dblp dataset

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to parse the xml file of dblp data set into a csv file. Now I am doing this with lxml module and testing the different functions to see what they return. 
However when I run the following code:

```
with open('F:\\21up\\Data\\dblp.xml', 'rb') as f:
    context = etree.iterparse(f, dtd_validation=True, events= ("start","end"))

context = iter(context)
event, root = next(context)
for event, ele in context:
    print event
    print ele
```

I got the ValueError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\21up\Data\XML2CSV", line 35, in <module>
    iterpar()
  File "F:\21up\Data\XML2CSV", line 28, in iterpar
    event, root = next(context)
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:131498)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I don't know how this happens. I have googled it but didn't find a suitable explanation yet. Can anyone tell me how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you process the context outside the with statement, which means, your file is closed by then.